# Using ffmpeg libraries in android native project

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

In my native android project I need to reduce a size of video file.

I've already built ffmpeg libraries for android.

How do I init ffmpeg libraries in my project and how to reduce video size without calling to ffmpeg in android command line.

Thanks in advance!